# how do i specify which array to iterate in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

let's pretend that the for loop evaluate if the symbol(s) in the list is in uptrend or downtrend, "i > 0" means uptrend and " i < 0" means downtrend

for example if i want to iterate throught a list in python i would do it this way:

```
uptrend = 0
downtrend = 0

list = ["AXP", "APPL", "MMM", "TSLA", "FB", "AMZN"]

for i in list:
    if i > 0:
        uptrend += 1

    else:
        downtrend += 1
```

how do i achieve this same code in pinescript?

so far what i did in pinescript is this:

```
uptrend = 0
downtrend = 0

string[] list = array.from("AXP", "APPL", "MMM", "TSLA", "FB", "AMZN")
```

but i am stuck on the for loop part because i cannot specify which array the i is from, in python i use (for i in list), what do i use in the place of "in" in pinescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pinescript` also supports `for .. in`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

var string[] list = array.from("AXP", "APPL", "MMM", "TSLA", "FB", "AMZN")
string s = ""

for i in list
    s := s + i + " "
    
var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = s)
```

[image]

Comment: here is the script i am working on, but i keep getting the "line 17: Cannot call 'request.security' with argument 'symbol'='i'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected" error. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1al_6M9Lzt24i1OQPEqKmb-JJ0tSN_IL_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well, that makes things different. As the error message said, you cannot use a `series string` for that argument. You cannot do what you want to do.

Comment: You need multiple `security()` calls for each ticker in your list.

Comment: okay thank you, i will generate the security calls code through python to save time. your help is much appreciated